# how to create a search feature without clicking the search button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

how to create a search feature without clicking the search button? so when entering a value then enter can immediately bring up the search results.

index.blade.php

```
<div class="input-group col-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" id="search-bar" placeholder="Type to search course">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-search">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

index_script.blade.php

```
$(".btn-search").click(function() {
                $(".see-more").click();
                $(".see-more").remove();

                var value =  $(".search-bar").val().toLowerCase();

                $(".course-item").filter(function() {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
                });

                $(".owl-item").filter(function() {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
                });

                $.each($("#ajar-catalog-container .owl-stage"), function() {
                    var count = 0;
                    $.each($(this).children('.owl-item'), function() {
                        display = $(this).children().css('display');
                        if (display == 'block') {
                            count++;
                        }
                    });

                    if(count == 0) {
                        $(this).closest('.card').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).closest('.card').css('display', 'block');
                    }
                });
            });
```

please help, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just manually trigger the click event of the button element.

```
$("#search-bar").keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(".btn-search").click();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Method #1

You can use the `oninput` event in JavaScript to get the results when entering a value to the input field.

```js
var searchInput = document.getElementById("search-bar")
searchInput.oninput = function(){
  // put your logic for search filter here
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group col-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" id="search-bar" placeholder="Type to search course">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-search">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Method #2 -

You can use jQuery's `keydown()` event

```js
$("#search-bar").keydown(function(){
   // your logic here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group col-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" id="search-bar" placeholder="Type to search course">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control btn-search">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```